# matplotlib PdfPages is ignoring set_xlim()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to save a seaborn scatter plot to multi page pdf using PdfPages(). I run the code as a python application, not in a notebook. The plot correctly sets the min & max of the x-axis if I run the same code snippet in a jupyter notebook, but when running in a py file saving as either a png or a multipage pdf the x-axis settings are ignored.

I have tried the following, but neither work

```
with PdfPages('scatter.pdf') as pdf:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        sns.scatterplot(data=pd.DataFrame(results), x="age", y="weight", hue="animal", ax=ax)
        plt.title('cats vs dogs')
        ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
        pdf.savefig(fig)
        plt.close(fig)


with PdfPages('scatter.pdf') as pdf:
        fig = plt.gcf()
        ax = plt.gca()
        sns.scatterplot(data=pd.DataFrame(results), x="age", y="weight", hue="animal", ax=ax)
        plt.title('cats vs dogs')
        ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
        pdf.savefig(fig)
        plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Does adding `%matplotlib inline` add the top of your code solve?

Comment: @DavidErickson I am running the python code from a .py file as an application. So `%matplotlib inline` is not applicable. Apologies that wasn't clear in the question, I will update it now

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using `seaborn==0.11.0`, `pandas==1.1.4`, `matplotlib==3.3.3` and a toy DataFrame like `results = pd.DataFrame({'age':range(8),'weight':range(8),'animal':range(8)})`